# Get the best from map and count

Tags: mysql, sql

I show you an example of what I need.

Table with these columns and data for example:

```
id  | mapname   | username  | score
----|-----------|-----------|--------
1   | mid_town  | carolina  | 5
2   | mid_town  | rupert    | 10
3   | id_room   | carolina  | 7
4   | mid_town  | mordor    | 14
5   | id_room   | intel     | 12
6   | id_room   | puyol     | 21
7   | pindle    | puyol     | 17
8   | pindle    | messi     | 28
9   | mid_town  | puyol     | 24
n   | unknown   | unknown   | unknown
```

I need the best from `mapname` order by `score` desc, but I don't know all map names.

So, in this case,

the best from `mid_town` is puyol with 24,

the best from `id_room` is puyol with 21,

the best from `pindle` is messi with 28.

Output:

```
puyol 2
messi 1
```

How to transform that in a single query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend answered it:

```
SELECT 
     t1.username, COUNT(t3.var2) as var1
FROM 
     data AS t1
JOIN
    (SELECT 
        t2.mapname, MAX(t2.score) as var2
        FROM data AS t2
        GROUP BY mapname) AS t3
ON t1.mapname = t3.mapname
AND t1.score = t3.var2
GROUP BY t1.username
ORDER BY var1 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select username, score from `table` where (mapname,score) in (select mapname, max(score) from `table` group by mapname)
```

Comment: I execute the query since five minutes ago and I still waiting, something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, mate:

```
SELECT
    username, score
FROM
    <your_table>
WHERE
    mapname = 'midtown'
HAVING
    score = MAX(SCORE)

UNION

SELECT
    username, score
FROM
    <your_table>
WHERE
    mapname = 'id_room'
HAVING
    score = MAX(SCORE)

UNION

SELECT
    username, score
FROM
    <your_table>
WHERE
    mapname = 'pindle'
HAVING
    score = MAX(SCORE);
```

or this one:

```
SELECT
    username, score
FROM
    <your_table>
GROUP BY
    mapname
ORDER BY
    score DESC;
```

Comment: [...] _but I don't know all map names._

Comment: try the other one, mate.